# Remove quote from the JSONArray output

Tags: java, gwt, arrays, json

On the successful call, I am getting the JSONArray with the key "objects" and again the testValue with the key "name". The output is Like:

```
"Abcd"
"Wxyz"
```

My code is as follows:

```java
public void onSuccess(JSONValue val) {
    JSONObject obj = val.isObject();
    JSONArray test = JSONUtil.getJSONArray(test, "objects");
    for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject childJSONObject = (JSONObject) test.get(i);
        JSONValue testValue = childJSONObject.get("name");
        System.out.println(testValue);
    }
}
```

Want to print the name as following: (Without Double Quote)

```
Abcd
Wxyz
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**1. .replaceAll()**

```
testValue.toString().replaceAll("\"", "");
```

This method replace all the double quotes which are present in your name not the first and the last.

Example : "Abcd" becomes Abcd but if the name is "Ab"cd" it should be Ab"cd according to your requirement but it becomes Abcd. Mean to say that all the double quote replaced.

**2. substring()**

If you want to use the substring method approach then use the following syntax to remove the first and the last double quotes from your string:

```
testValue.toString().subString(1,testValue.toString().length()-1);
```

`1` - indicates the first character of the string

`testValue.toString().length()-1` : indicates the last character of the string.

**For your case `.substring()` method is more better than the `.replaceAll()`, if `.getString()` not working.**

**3. .ValueOf() OR .getString()**

Don't know In your case why it is not working ? (may be because the string itself containing the quotes) other wise the best way is to Convert the JSONValue to the String as `String.ValueOf(testValue);`

OR

`childJSONObject.getString("name");`

Otherwise give preference as :  3 > 2 > 1

Comment: The correct answer, in these days, is to cast to JsonString then use getString() method.

Comment: @user2070007 answer is more straightforward and correct way of handling this

Answer (score 8):

This thread is pretty old, but I stumbled upon the same problem an hour ago and found the correct solution. You have to check for the type of JsonValue and if its a JsonString, you can parse it to JsonString and call its getString() method.

```
if(val.getValueType().equals(JsonValue.ValueType.STRING)) {
  c.setValue(((JsonString) val).getString());
} else {
  c.setValue(val.toString());
}
```

Comment: In these days, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

Convert the JSONValue back to String:

```
String.ValueOf(testValue);
```

Or

```
childJSONObject.getString("name");
```

After all this and still end up with quotes - then fall back on RegExp.

```
testValue.toString().replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

just

```
s.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

removes all " characters in your string.

or in your case

```
testValue.toString().replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Comment: @Ask You shouldn't have to remove those quotes, you'd better get the proper  String value.

Comment: @AminAbu-Taleb I am using JSONValue testValue = childJSONObject.get("name"); but instead of this String testValue = childJSONObject.getString("name"); is not working for me.giving some casting error.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the below to get string without double quotes

```
    JsonObject childJSONObject = new JsonObject(); 
   JSONValue testValue = childJSONObject.get("name").getAsString();
```

this gives the string without double quotes `" "` in the string

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value as a String itself, don't need to cast or replace:

```
JSONObject childJSONObject = (JSONObject) test.get(i);
String testValue = childJSONObject.getString("name");
```

It will return a String without quotes.

More info: [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I am using  JSONValue testValue = childJSONObject.get("name"); but instead of this String testValue = childJSONObject.getString("name"); is not working for me.giving some casting error.

Comment: its not allow me to apply the getString() method. only i am able to implement with get() method. Im my case the JSON i am getting itself containg the double quote so if converting in string no change because the string itself containing the quote.

Comment: Is there any other way to remove the quotes from the begining and the end using substring format or something else..?

Comment: +1 but still not solving my problem. only getting correct result with the help of testValue.toString().replaceAll("\"", "");

Comment: The correct answer, in these days, is to cast to JsonString then use getString() method.

Answer (score 2):

In case of using javax.json.JsonArray
you can get the String of an JsonValue so:

```
JsonArray array = jsonObject.getJsonArray("languages");
for (int i=0; i<array.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(array.getJsonString(i).getString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

quotes in arrays depends on which JOSN Lib are using:

org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray
or
org.json.JSONArray

Answer (score 1):

String mailMessage = JSONObject.toJSONString("JsonObject").replace("\"", " ").trim();

Comment: You should explain how your solution works and not just past some code.

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to use `.getString()` method of JSONObject or  `.valueOf()` method of String.
 You can also use the `.replaceAll("\"","")`, but this has some problems, when the string itself contains `"`(double quotes) embedded in it. So, avoid using the replaceAll() method to get out of the unexpected problems.

But still, if you want to code on own by your hand or If you want to know how to delete the double quotes without using `getString() and  .valueOf()`, you can try like this

```
testValue.toString().subString(1,testValue.toString().length())
```

it will give the sub string excluding first and last characters of the String. But, it seems like some messy thing.

Comment: @Azzez: Looks good the substrig solution.Which one is better substring ot replaceAll() . Any Idea...?

Comment: Out of those two options, substring is best option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `com.google.gwt.json.client.*` here (from question tags and use of `JSONValue` which is hardly found anywhere else), `toString()` is meant to give you a JSON representation of the value.

Here, the value is a `JSONString`, so you need to use:

```
testValue.isString().stringValue()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
JSON.parse(JSON.Stringify(this_has_quotes));
```

Is all you need! `JSON.Stringify()` will get the value of the key accordingly. And `JSON.parse()` will parse your value and return the "dry" value without quote.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is

```
defect.get("FormattedID").toString().substring(1,defect.get("FormattedID").toString().length()-1)
```

Comment: Others did not work, so I have shared mine. Let me know reason for -1 please.