# Java - How to convert values within JSON String (remove quotes on non-strings)?

Tags: java, json

I have a String, representing a JSON, e.g.

```
      {"someId":"2130706433","someValue":"Android","networkId":"0","someTag":"true", ...}
```

Now I want to remove the quotes, but only where I can (numbers and booleans). How do I best do this (in Java)?

Result should look like:

```
       {"someId":2130706433,"someValue":"Android","networkId":0,"someTag":true, ...}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Why don't you chose to convert it into an object using `jackson` or java api ?

Comment: Try parsing it into a JSONObject, and then truning it back to a String however you like. I prefer using JSONSimple but thats up to you to decide :- ) **EDIT**: There may be a suffisticated way to do it through regex's that i am not aware of.

Comment: Take a look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879568/remove-quote-from-the-jsonarray-output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879568/remove-quote-from-the-jsonarray-output)

Comment: If I convert to an object, the problem is, since the values are quoted it is still recognized as a String, no matter what data type actually is in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a fairly simple regex replace:

```
jsonString.replaceAll("\"([0-9]+|true)\"", "$1");
```

if every number and boolean in quotes is to be replaced.