# JAVA pusher string connections

Tags: java, android, pusher

So I have the following senario:

I have a browser which will act as my pusher server,
my mobile app as a client.

Now I want to pair the browser to the phone and have them both connect to the same channel that's dynamically made up by the browser, that will send a message to my device and tell it to connect to X channel. Now I'm getting stuck at the app section on how to get the device to connect to a channel that's sent over Pusher.

I have the following code in JAVA :

```
 public void openPusherListener() {


    //default settings for pusher
    PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setCluster("eu");
    final Pusher pusher = new Pusher(API_KEY, options);


    pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
            String socketId = pusher.getConnection().getSocketId();
            Log.d("socketID", socketId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
            System.out.println("There was a problem connecting!");
        }
    }, ConnectionState.CONNECTED);




    Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("waitlist");//Default channel to join


    channel.bind("test", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(String channelName, String eventName, final String data) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonObject mydata = gson.fromJson(data, JsonObject.class);

            Log.d("PUSHER - channel", String.valueOf(mydata.get("channel")));

            String myChannel = String.valueOf(mydata.get("channel")).replace('"', ' ');

            Log.d("TEST MYCHANNEL", String.valueOf(mydata.get("channel")));


            Channel channel = pusher.subscribe(myChannel);//This doesnt work.

            channel.bind("test2", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(String channelName, String eventName, final String data) {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    JsonObject mydata = gson.fromJson(data, JsonObject.class);

                    Log.d("TEST2 PUSHER", String.valueOf(mydata.get("joinChannel")));
                }
            });



        }
    });
    pusher.connect();
}
```

Sadly the joining the 2nd channel doesnt work, I'm receiving the following error:

```
I/System.out: There was a problem connecting!
```

On Pusher I can see the following:

```
Invalid channel name ' test2 ' (bad chars)
```

Now I take that I have to find a way of connecting to the channel without sending quotes to it aswell, so I was wondering how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got managed to get it to work, since I was using Gson and that will always set double quotes around the string to it's easier to put it back into another json array, you would need to do:

```
String myChannel = mydata.get("channel").getAsString();
```

this will grab the string without the double quotes.

[Remove quote from the JSONArray output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879568/remove-quote-from-the-jsonarray-output)